# django-admin, add hyperlink in list_display to other application

Tags: python, django, django-admin

under : mydomain/admin, I have several applications

App1,

app1modle1,

app2model2,

App2,

app2model1,

app2model2,

App3,

app3model1.

In App3model1, say for each 'user',I want to add a column in list_display, and the content is a hyperlink to a corresponding model/table in App2, say what does the user sell, one-to-many relation.

eg:

under app3model1 (the link is mydomain/admin/app3/model1)

u1,link

u2,link,

u3,link.

and under app2model2 (the original view, link is mydomain/admin/app2/model2)

u1,apple,$5

u1,orange,$10

u2,apple, $10

u3, grape, $5

Once I click the 'link' next to u1 in app3model1, I want to see mydomain/admin/app2/model2/?q=u1

u1,apple,$5

u1,orange,$10

I have tried the following code in App3/admin.py:

```
list_display = ['username', 'link']     
def link(self, obj):
    seller_link = 'admin/app2/model2/?q=' + obj.username
    return format_html("<a href= %s >link</a>" % seller_link)
```

but it directs me to mydomain/admin/app3/model1/admin/app2/model2...and what I want is mydomain/admin/app2/model2.. with parameters. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding a leading slash here `seller_link = '/admin/app2/model2/?q=' + obj.username` ?

Comment: @BUZZY you are my hero.